# Many to many relationship with Django, Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, relation

Currently i work on an application to manage drivers for cars and events written in Django, Python.

I have the two Models:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    max_capacity    = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    available       = models.BooleanField()

class Event(models.Model):
    start_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    end_timestamp   = models.DateTimeField()
    description     = models.TextField()
    location        = LatLonField()
```

I've a pool of 10 different vehicles saved.
There are 18 different Events.

Now i want to add multiple Vehicles to an event **without to generate new ones** for every event, and specify a number of people which will be using this car for this event like:

```
Event 0815:
    - FirstCar,  loaded with 5/13 People
    - SecondCar, loaded with 2/2 People
```

(The max capacity of a car is given in it's Model)

How is this with the structure of djangos database concept possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [intermediate table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and use the `through` argument of the `ManyToMany` field:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    vehicles = models.ManyToManyField(Vehicle, through='EventVehicle')

class EventVehicle(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
    loaded = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

Comment: I'll give it a try later on, but this seems to help me!

Comment: Note that with intermediate model you have to use the admin inlines to edit the list of event's vehicles instead of the simple M2M field.